# Display name of active layout in GNU-Screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I have multiple layouts in my GNU-Screen. Is it possible to display the name of the currently-used layout in the status bar of Screen?

Comment: You can always use `Ctrl`+`A` and then type `:layout show` but it sounds like you're asking for the layout title to always be there and not require an extra command.

Comment: Using @kichik's comment, I was able to show layout while changing it.  
`bindkey "^[[15~" eval "layout prev" "layout show"`
`bindkey "^[[17~" eval "layout next" "layout show"`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this is what you need.

```
# the following two lines give a two-line status, with the current window highlighted
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string '%{= kG}[%{G}%H%? %1`%?%{g}][%= %{= kw}%-w%{+b yk} %n*%t%?(%u)%? %{-}%+w %=%{g}][%{B}%m/%d %{W}%C%A%{g}]'
```

Source : [Gist link](https://gist.github.com/joaopizani/2718397)

Sample :

[image]

Comment: I am using this solution for highlighting name of current window. However I need to show and highlight name of current layout.